# お互いに in お互いに頑張ろう

Tags: meaning

I came across the following example in my dictionary (Wisdom Japanese-English).

> お互いに頑張ろう
> Let’s do our best.

Why is お互いに used here? My understanding is that お互いに signifies a mutual action and that 頑張る is not mutual. Is this understanding incorrect?

Comment: A slightly more literal translation could be “let’s *both* do our best”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you know the meaning of 頑張って、頑張ろう、頑張れ etc. The exact meaning of these phrases is hard to pin down. Culturally and semantically, they are an equivalent of "Good luck!" "Do your best!" "Go for it!"

お互いに頑張ろう/頑張りましょう is a really common expression, conveying a very simple idea. For example, say A is a student and A's class is having a test tomorrow. It is very common and idiomatic for A to say to their friends:

> お互い頑張ろうね！

It means A hopes their friends will do their best and get good results, and at the same time those wishes are also directed at A themself. Also implied in that line is A saying, "I will also do my best, and I hope I will get a good score too, (in addition to wishing y'all good luck)."